# The process appears to be deadlocked

Tags: c++, deadlock

```
void Simulator::writeData()
{ 
  resultFile_<<"#"<<*gTime_<<"\n"; 
  Wire* wire=wires_->next;
  char* c=0;
  while(wire!=0)
  {
      if(wire->getType() ==TYPE_OUT)
      {
          c=wire->getValue();
              resultFile_<<"b"<<c<<" "<<wire->getName()<<"\n";  //output result

          //// for vector of results://///
          Tlogic tempEntery(wire->getSize());
          tempEntery.setTime(*gTime_);
          tempEntery.setLogic(c);
          goldenResult_.push_back(tempEntery);
          ////////////////////////////////

      }
   wire=wire->next; 
  } 
} //end of function writeData
```

In this Code , i need a temp chat* variable , i named it c, 
i allocate a memory to it an then delete,
question: 
my program call this function correctly and it works, 
but for tenth time that i call this, program breaks and when i pause it this error appears:
The process appears to be deadlocked.

this is error:
The process appears to be deadlocked( or is not running any user-mode code). All threads have been stopped.  + an OK button!

..................
I think its because of my vector ( goldenResult_) !! because when i comment that line there is no deadlocking
how can I fix this error ?

Comment: You have a memory leak - use delete [] for deallocating ARRAY type memory

Comment: Could you please specify, how exactly it crashes? Are we looping in the while eternally? If so, the linked list wire might be circular and we'll never get out of the loop.

Comment: There is yet another problem - you are calling delete on c variable when it's not initialized. Since it's a local variable, it will contain some random data. When you call delete, the memory manager might gobble it silently and crash a bit later, or do it immediately.

Comment: no Im not looping in while,    it shows console window and nothing will happen till press pause button and it shows that error, when i press OK , it opens crtmbox.c and a green arrow that shows program should continue from here, this that code in crtmbox.c :     #ifdef _UNICODE
                            GetProcAddress(hlib, "MessageBoxW")))
#else  /* _UNICODE */
                            GetProcAddress(hlib, "MessageBoxA")))
#endif  /* _UNICODE */
                return 0;

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating/freeing memory subject to external conditions that cannot be determined from the code shown. My suggestion is to correct the allocation idiom: initialize the pointer to 0, and set to 0 after delete:

```
  char* c = 0; // be sure you don't free if not allocated
  while(wire!=0)
  {
      if(wire->getType() ==TYPE_OUT)
      {
          c=new char[wire->getSize()+1] ;
          wire->getValue(c);
              resultFile_<<"b"<<c<<" "<<wire->getName()<<"\n";  //output result

          //// for vector of results://///
          Tlogic tempEntery(wire->getSize());
          tempEntery.setTime(*gTime_);
          tempEntery.setLogic(c);
          goldenResult_.push_back(tempEntery);
          ////////////////////////////////
         // delete c;
      }
      delete c ; // this can remain unchanged: delete of NULL is harmless
      c = 0;  // this way you avoid to delete more times than allocated
      wire=wire->next; 
  }
```

an alternative would be using a smart pointer, that keeps track of allocation for you.

Comment: i Changed my code as you said but i still have this problem!!                   it shows console window and nothing will happen till press pause button and it shows that error, when i press OK , it opens crtmbox.c and a green arrow that shows program should continue from here, this is that code in crtmbox.c :                                       #ifdef _UNICODE GetProcAddress(hlib, "MessageBoxW"))) #else /* _UNICODE / GetProcAddress(hlib, "MessageBoxA"))) #endif / _UNICODE */ return 0;

Comment: sorry, I'm unable to guess what the problem could be. Surely the above suggestion corrects a **potential** problem. Try to post the corrected code, adding to your question...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is:

```
   tempEntery.setTime(*gTime_); <--- (hm... gTime ... race somewhere ?? )
   tempEntery.setLogic(c);
   goldenResult_.push_back(tempEntery);
```

can you show part that process your vector ?

Sorry that not in comments, not enough points.